# Well-regarded institutions offering distance education (PG) in applied Math

Tags: graduate-school, distance-learning

Which are the well-regarded institutions in Europe (apart from the Open University in the UK) and America offering distance learning postgraduate degrees? I'm especially interested in Applied Mathematics.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for places teaching in English?

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Yes.

Comment: It would help if you clarify what kind of degree you are looking for (masters or doctorate, the latter is unlikely to exist) and what you plan to do with it (industry, teaching, ?)

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of schools that have distance-learning programs, including for applied mathematics. For instance, the University of Washington offers an [online master's of science program in Applied Mathematics](http://www.amathonline.uw.edu/).

Comment: I had to edit this comment to help avoid vandalism. Answers under about 300 characters can be easily vandalized.

Comment: @aeismail, indeed, someone just tried to vandalize it again just now.

Comment: @aeismail: This answer keeps receiving vandalism, do you know what's the connection with the number of characters?